# How do you unit test PageContext.Current.Item?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm currently creating a unit test for an action result method:-

```
public virtual ActionResult MyControllerTest(){
 var pageItem = PageContext.Current.Item
...
 
 return ViewOrErrorResult<string>(null);
}
```

Unit test goes like this:-

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void MyControllerTest_Results(params){
 //assign
 var pageContext = Substitute.For<PageContext>();
 ContextService.Get().Push(pageContext);

 //Act
 ...
 //Assert

}
```

However, `PageContext.Current.Item` is always null. Anyone has tried mocking `PageContext.Current.Item`?
Thanks

Comment: Borj, while my answer shows hot to set the item, it would be great to understand what exactly you're trying to test. It's not clear why do you call `ContextService.Get().Push(pageContext);` and what should happen after. Please extend the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt to utilize static prop `PageContext.Current` indeed can be cumbersome. While it is an [Ambient Context](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/), Sitecore implementation does not let you mock and set it easily. Even if you do, you'll get concurency issues running your tests in parallel.

A better approach would to *inject* an instance of `PageContext` in the code where you wanted to use static `PageContext.Current` prop. The PageContext can be easily mocked and configured. See below.

`PageContext.Item` property has a public setter. Just set the item there and that's it:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void PageContextItemTest(
    [Substitute] PageContext pageContext,
    Item current)
{
    pageContext.Item = current;
    Assert.Same(current, pageContext.Item); // pass
}
```

There is a list of customizations that simplify the Item creating using `AutoFixture` and `AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute` libraries:

```
public class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(() => new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization())
            .Customize(new DatabaseCustomization())
            .Customize(new ItemCustomization())
            .Customize(new FieldCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

internal class DatabaseCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Inject(Substitute.For<Database>());
    }
}

internal class ItemCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Item>(x =>
            x.FromFactory(() => CreateItem(fixture))
                .OmitAutoProperties()
        );
    }

    private static Item CreateItem(ISpecimenBuilder fixture)
    {
        var item = Substitute.For<Item>(
            fixture.Create<ID>(),
            ItemData.Empty,
            fixture.Create<Database>());
        item.Name.Returns("item_" + fixture.Create<string>());
        item.Children.Returns(Substitute.For<ChildList>(item, new List<Item>()));
        item.Fields.Returns(Substitute.For<FieldCollection>(item));

        var language = Language.Parse("en");
        item.Language.Returns(language);
        item.Languages.Returns(new[] { language });

        var template = Substitute.For<TemplateItem>(Substitute.For<Item>(
            fixture.Create<ID>(),
            ItemData.Empty,
            fixture.Create<Database>()));
        item.Template.Returns(template);

        item.Version.Returns(Version.First);
        item.Versions.Returns(Substitute.For<ItemVersions>(item));
        item.Versions.Count.Returns(1);

        return item;
    }
}

internal class FieldCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Field>(x =>
            x.FromFactory(() => CreateField(fixture))
                .OmitAutoProperties()
        );
    }

    private static Field CreateField(ISpecimenBuilder fixture)
    {
        var item = fixture.Create<Item>();
        var field = Substitute.For<Field>(
            fixture.Create<ID>(),
            item);
        field.Database.Returns(item.Database);

        return field;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The customaizations above are samples. They mock items and props and let you extend it further as needed. For instance, if you need *some* template id, you can extend the ItemCustomization `Create` method with the following line and generate random id:

```
item.TemplateID.Returns(fixture.Create<ID>());
```

If you need a specific template Id in your test, you can set it *in the test*:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void SetCustomTemplateId(Item item, ID expected)
{
    item.TemplateID.Returns(expected);
    Assert.Same(expected, item.TemplateID);
}
```

Same about verstions.

Comment: Hello this one works, thanks. however how do you assign values to its other properties such as version and templateID? tried assigning but it says property is ready only.

myItem = myItem .Versions[Version.Latest]; -> Versions is null. TemplateID is null as well.

Comment: +1 for highlighting and referencing the article on Ambient Context